# How the object created by dojo.declare can access its own properties?

Tags: javascript, dojo, declare

I have some conceptual problem with using Dojo's class-like objects created with dojo/_base/declare.

I have created the following module:

```javascript
define(["dojo/_base/declare", ....], function(declare,....){
    return declare('my.widget', null ,function(..){
     startup: function() {
       ....
       new Button({onClick: this.newItem}, newButtonNode)
     },
     newItem: function() {
       this.openDialog({}, this.saveItemCallback)
     },
     openDialog: function(item,callback){...},
     saveItemCallback: function(item){....}
    })
})
```

The problem is, that the function `newItem` isn't functioning, because when it's called from button click, `this` points to Button widget, and not to the 'my.widget' instance.

I'm confused. How can I refer to the 'my.widget' instance? In the Dojo classes I've read the current instance is available under `this`.

Comment: For the `openDialog` function, bear in mind that sometimes it's cleaner to [return a `Promise`](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/promises/) rather than requiring callbacks as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you then want to call `newItem` with the correct scope, you could use the `dojo/_base/lang`, `hitch()` function.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", ....], function(declare, lang, ....){
    return declare('my.widget', null ,function(..){
     startup: function() {
       new Button({onClick: lang.hitch(this, "newItem"}, newButtonNode)
     },
     newItem: function() {
       this.openDialog({}, this.saveItemCallback)
     },
     openDialog: function(item,callback){...},
     saveItemCallback: function(item){....}
    })
});
```

The `hitch()` function will make sure that the `this` reference is correct. This sounds like real magic, but it uses some kind of reflection behind the screens to execute the function.

What it really does is using the `Function.prototype.apply` function to get the magic started. As you can read in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) it accepts a context and the parameters. So it will in fact change the `this` reference when `newItem` is executed.

Comment: OK, but it's not the problem. The problem is, that for the newItem function, 'this' is the Button, not 'myInstance'. 'myInstance' is visible only within 'startup' function.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. fixed it. It's pretty much the same as Chris Hayes posted, but with the new AMD syntax.

Comment: Yest, this is it! I have still problems understanding, what 'hitch' is doing.

Comment: I editted my answer to explain what `hitch` does. Behind the screens it's using some kind of reflection to do the magic stuff. There is a function called `apply` which allows you to modify what `this` is referring to.

Comment: Yet, knowing what to search, I've found multiple usages of lang.hitch in Dojo code, so your answer is the canonical way of doing things in Dojo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dojo.hitch` to attach a context to a function:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", ....], function(declare,....){
    var myFunc = dojo.hitch(this, function() { 
       this.openDialog({}, this.saveItemCallback)
    });

    return declare('my.widget', null ,function(..){
     startup: function() {
       ....
       new Button({onClick: this.newItem}, newButtonNode)
     },
     newItem: myFunc,
     openDialog: function(item,callback){...},
     saveItemCallback: function(item){....}
    })
})
```

By doing so, you are effectively stating that within the anonymous function passed to `dojo.hitch`, `this` refers to the first argument passed (which could be any object).

Comment: By doing so I've got error even before the object was created, within the myFunc declaration: 'this.openDialog is undefined'